# Querying JSONB[] postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, sequelize.js, jsonb

I am facing a trouble during query JSONB[] I have tried raw query on postgres like this

```
select * from "Certification" where (test -> 'dea')::jsonb like '%"xyz"%'
```

but it says error on `->` operator. Data is there as shown in attached picture. Thanks in advance. I spend 2 hours in searching and i got nothing how to query `JSONB[]` in `postgres` with working example. All example i tried and there is syntax error operator not exist [image]

Comment: column with `jsonb[]` almost never makes sense. If you want to store an array of elements. Use a `jsonb` column that stores a JSON array.

Answer (score 0):

Use `->>` instead of `->`. `->>` gives the value of the key on which you want to apply `where` clause.

```
select * from "Certification" where test ->> 'dea' like '%"xyz"%';
```

Or this,

```
select * from "Certification" where test::jsonb ->> 'dea' like '%"xyz"%';
```

Comment: ERROR:  operator does not exist: jsonb[] ->> unknown
LINE 1: select * from "Certification" where (test ->> 'dea')::jsonb ...
                                                  ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
Character: 43

Comment: Try removing that type cast? As in `test ->> 'dea'` not `(test ->> 'dea')::jsonb`